# 100% clientside jquery shoppingcart

Tags: jquery, client-side, shopping-cart

I know clientside webcarts could be modified by the visitor, in my application that is OK.
The only webacart without serverside logic and validation I have found is simplecart-js. However it is not using jquery.

Can anyone suggest a jquery cart with the same functionalities, or even more basic? I assume it would make use of the ezcookie plugin to store the cart contents into a cookie.

Comment: It should be pretty easy to make your own actually, and you'll get to know jQuery quite intimately :) reow

Comment: Something like [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/smartcart)? I haven't tried it, but it looks like it might be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this plugin for **jQuery** called **Smartcart** that sounds like *exactly* what your looking for

[<strike>Example</strike>](http://fivelist.summerhost.info/labs/SmartCart/index.php)

[<strike>Documentation</strike>](http://fivelist.summerhost.info/products.php?product=scat&action=2)

[Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartcart1/)

Comment: I wanted to use jquery bc it is used for other things in my application, hosted at google, and so cut on load times. I assumed that the actual code for the cart would be just a few kb's on top of the jquery core...
However looking at the smartcart footprint, together with ezcookie to give it storage;

jquery-1.3.2.min.js  55.9kb
jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js 188.4 kb
jquery.scrollTo-min.js  2.2 kb
SmartCart.js   8.5 kb
+
ezcookie    5.3kb

The non-jquery simplecart comes in at only 15.1 kb, minified. So jquery might be easier but certainly not smaller?